# Can anyone explain output of this program

Tags: c, recursion, function-definition

static variable example with recursion function

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        static int i=10;
        if(--i)
        {
            main(); /*recursive call main */
            printf("%d ", ++i); /* print returned value of main */

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what problems you have, what is the output you expected? What is the actual output? And do take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `printf("%d ", ++i); /* print returned value of main */` the comment here is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

While `i` is not equal to zero the function main calls itself.

```
    if(--i)
    {
        main(); /*recursive call main */
```

So you have a chain of calls

```
main( i = 10 ) -> main( i = 9 ) ->...-> main( i = 0 )
```

When `i` is equal to zero then the recursion stops and each called main returns the control to the previous call of main.

The previous call of main just execute this statement

```
printf("%d ", ++i); /* print returned value of main */
```

Thus the output will be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Got it Thank you, 
so the called main returns from last to first order right??

Comment: @SiddharthSidhu Yes at first main is called until i is equal to 0 then it returns the control to the previous call. Consider the case when i initially is equal to 1. In this case nothing will be outputted because --i is equal to 0 and it was the first call of main that is there is no other calls of main.

Answer (score 1):

`++i` is the same as `i = i + 1` so when you write

```
printd("%d ", ++i);
```

you increment `i` again so its value stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variable is initialized once. And its lifetime is of the program. As variable is initialized once, it will have initial value of 10.

In every recursive call, it will be decremented (at `if` statement) and when reached to 0, it will not recur further.

After the last recursion, it will start printing and return.

As `printf` statement is after recursion, it will start first printing after last recursion (when `i=1`) and will print 1 to 9.

While executing `printf` and returning, it will keep increasing `i` by 1. Hence, topmost function stack will get `i` as 9.